# An argument named "resource_group" is not expected here

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

trying to deploy resource group but getting below error

Error: Unsupported argument

on auto.tfvars.tf line 1:
1: resource_group = "india1111"

An argument named "resource_group" is not expected here.

code

[code attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqFLT.png)

Comment: Can you attach the code in the question. Instead of in a screen shot?

Comment: Do you have any more questions? Do you mind marking this answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if there is no need to further help?

Answer (score 0):

You could specfiy the variable values with file `.auto.tfvars` instead of `auto.tfvars.tf`.

For example, the content of the `variables.tf` file.

```
variable "resource_group" {
    type = string
}
```

The content of the `.auto.tfvars` file.

```
resource_group = "trafff"
```

To specify variable values in a variable definitions file (with a filename ending in either `.tfvars` or `.tfvars.json`) and then specify that file on the command line with `-var-file`:

```
terraform apply -var-file="testing.tfvars"
```

Terraform also automatically loads a number of variable definitions files if they are present:

- Files named exactly `terraform.tfvars` or `terraform.tfvars.json.`
- Any files with names ending in `.auto.tfvars` or `.auto.tfvars.json`.

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files

Comment: This helped me out a lot!!